# How to resize meshes in URDF?

Tags: rviz, urdf, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently drawing out my robot using URDF. I am at the end of the first URDF tutorial (see http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch#Finishing_the_Model). My  problem: once I added my mesh, it is very disproportionate to the rest of the drawing, and I have no idea how to resize the mesh. The tutorial states that: "Meshes can also be sized using relative scaling parameters or a bounding box size"

where do I find an example? Where is the documentation? and if no documentation or examples exist, could you please provide an example of code for a "bounding box" or "relative scaling"?

More detail:

image before meshes are added in urdf file:

[image: image description]

image after meshes are added in urdf file:

[image: image description]

the code importing the meshes:

```
   <!-- *********************(21) LMS LINK - MESHES****************************-->
  <!-- a "link" is the part that we are creating. All the internal tags describe
       this part. This is the body of Jimmy (both square levels) -->
  <link name="LMS_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <!--box dimensions is Meters. L X W X H where the L X H is a rectangle, 
            and the H extrudes it upwards -->
        <mesh filename="package://urdf_tutorial/meshes/LMS-200-30106.dae"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
    
    <!-- *********************(22) LMS to LMS PLATE JOINT **********************-->
    <!-- a joint allows us to create a relationship between two links (parts)-->
      <joint name="LMS_to_LMS_plate_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="LMS_plate_link"/>
        <child link="LMS_link"/>
        <!-- this is the point at which the two parts attach to one another-->
        <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
      </joint>
```

I am building a URDF because it was suggested here: https://answers.ros.org/question/271819/please-suggest-all-packages-to-achieve-slam-for-robot/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273434/how-to-resize-meshes-in-urdf?/) by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2017-10-18

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-19**:
@BuilderMike: please attach your images to your question directly. I've given you enough karma to do that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-19**:
Also: I would advise you follow regular [ROS Naming conventions](http://wiki.ros.org/Names) when naming `link`s and `joint`s as well. In summary: no capitals, anywhere, no whitespace, no special chars.

**Comment by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on 2017-10-19**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for the karma, I updated all my questions to include images instead of links. Also, thank you for the link to the URDF XML wiki.... I missed it when reading the tutorial. As for the naming convention, thanks for pointing out my error. Is there a document outlining these conventions?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
re: conventions: I think I linked you to those ("ROS Naming conventions").

If you're looking for joint/link/frame naming conventions, there is [geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions), but it's not too explicit.

No capitals or special chars ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-20**:
.. and no whitespace just makes sense: no guessing as to how someone CaPiTaLiseD their frames, no weird international char / localisation issues, etc.

I always follow [wiki/Names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names) with everything (files, directories, xacros, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should do it:

```
<mesh filename="package://pkg_name/filepath/your_stl.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
```

Alternatively, you could install Blender. It lets you scale stl's and also change the coordinate frame. See http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i2

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on 2017-10-18**:
Hi AndyZe, Thanks for your answer and suggestion, At this point, I have so many packages to learn that it's overwhelming. Could you expand your answer on what the scale values mean? is it % or actual distance units, and if so which ones? Is there any documentation for this xml tag in a URDF context?

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-10-18**:
It's just multiplied by that factor. So in my example, the STL would be 1/1000th of the original size.

**Comment by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on 2017-10-18**:
How did you know this... is there documentation on this xml tag somewhere? Thank you very much for your answer it did work for me.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-10-18**:
Tribal knowledge. But seriously, I learned it from another person firsthand.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-19**:\

> Tribal knowledge

This is all documented on the wiki, see [wiki/urdf/XML](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML).

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-21**:
Negative scale values do a flip/mirror image on that axis, a left wheel can become a right wheel and so on, which is less trouble than having to maintain separate otherwise identical mesh files.